# Should I be sincere - in an interview - about the reason for leaving my previous job?

Tags: interviewing

I find myself in a situation similar to the man who wrote this post [Lack of recognition in role and career development within role](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3481/lack-of-recognition-in-role-and-career-development-within-role) , 
that is to say I feel:

1. I'm doing much more work with respect to what I'm paid for
2. I'm doing work which go beyond the responsibility of my role
3. The extra work, extra efforts, and skills I have are not recognized by my boss, so he lets me do simple tasks rather than more advanced ones (even more productive).

These are more or less the reasons for I'm thinking of quitting my job and finding another one.

If I go for an interview, do you think I should be frank about the reasons why I want to quit the job? Or could such sincerity boomerang on me?

Comment: It depends on who's interviewing you. You have good reasons, but the person sitting on the opposite side of the table has to have the capacity to understand and appreciate them - that's not going to be everyone.

Comment: Never give good thought to a canned question that can best be answered with a canned answer

Comment: The best canned answer to that canned question is "I don't use interviews as a venue to air my current company's dirty laundry."

Comment: All of those feelings can be summed up as "I'm looking to advance my career".  Everything else is just details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it not a good idea to "badmouth" a previous employer?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/42121/why-is-it-not-a-good-idea-to-badmouth-a-previous-employer)

Comment: Very few people who express sentiments about being overworked, underpaid, or underpromoted will be found as more enticing to a potential employer.  Smart employers are well aware that MOST people leave their jobs due to discouraging interactions with their manager...  That still leaves room for "bad employee, good manager" and every other permutation. If you're going to open that can of worms to scrutiny, little personal good is likely to result (but as the employer, I'd be glad that you did, because it would be easier to turn you down in spite of your skills)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I'd go with cautious honesty. :)

Always state your reasons for leaving in positive terms - "I want a new challenge, I work hard at my job, and I'm looking for opportunities for advancement.  I'd really like (this big advanced work that you're not currently doing but would like to do) and there's not much opportunity for that in my current role. this job is perfect because..." is great.  "I'm overworked, underpaid, taking on more than my role dictates and never getting recognized in either money, promotions or interesting assignments" can come off like a rant.

Both are honest, but having goals and dreams is a very enticing quality in a new hire.  Having a buildup of frustration and disgruntledness is not.

Comment: I agree; when I changed jobs last year, there was a buildup of frustration, and in my interview for the position I have now I got rid of that frustration by framing answers to interview questions in terms of what I would do at the new company, having learned what didn't work (and why) at the old place.  I also eventually poached all my good people from the old place, but that's neither here nor there... :)

Comment: I agree with using your canned positive terms.  But lets face it this is not honesty.  The honesty is the OP hated his last job and quit before he got a new one because of that.  Disguising your feelings is dishonest especially when you spin them.  I get that it is how the game is played but pretending it is anything other than dishonesty is well dishonest

Comment: I simply disagree.  If you can't *honestly* look at your line of work and intended career goals in a positive light, then look for a new career.  I think if there's no way you can genuinely frame your search and your reason for leaving in a positive way, then I have serious concerns about whether you can frame *other* work-related problems in a positive way, and thus serious concerns about hiring such a person.  I didn't write the examples to be "canned", I wrote them as a sample.

Answer (score 12):

I would generically encapsulate your reasons as **lacking vision of perspective in the current position and pursuing career growth**. I am not sure about the culture in Italy, which is certainly a factor, but I can tell you that, in the U.S., honesty about hitting a dead end in your existing career or menial duties is in 98% of cases punished. Why? Because it is self-incriminating as an admission of professional shortfalls and you should never ever say anything in an interview that does not work in your favor of making a sale. An interviewer is not a shoulder to cry on, it is someone to make a sale to. I understand you may be tempted to be honest or to even rant about frustrations in your current job. Don't do it. Just like Chad said in his comment, **those are canned questions and are not worth a well thought out and honest answer**. So be pragmatic and don't forget the interview is not a shrink session, not a chat with your BFF, not a place to be overly honest -- it's the cusp of a market place and your mission is to make the sale.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few pitfalls here I'd be careful to avoid:

1. Blaming the former workplace - If you talk down about where you worked before, then the people interviewing you may fear being in a similar situation in the future.
2. Follow-ups to these responses - As you give these answers, there may be questions from the interviewer of, "What did you do about these concerns?" that may not be a question you're prepared to answer in a positive light.
3. Putting yourself in a less than great light - This would be bethlakshmi's response where if you answer in less than positive terms, it may not go over well.

Answer (score 1):

**The Grass Isn't Always Greener**
Do some research and decide why you think the new job is better than your current one. Just because one opportunity is better, doesn't mean the other one is bad. Although you may not have been compensated/recognized for your efforts, you current company does let you do more. You can now put these accomplishments on your resume/CV and get a better job.

Some interviewers may notice the discrepancy between your title and actual responsibilities. Let them know you took the initiative to do more, but the company didn't have the room to promote you. It happens.

Some day you're going to have to explain why you're leaving a good job.