# Is there any problem with my saying about the leaving reason for current company in an interview (career change)?

Tags: interviewing, career-development, job-change, career-switch

I am planning on changing my career to internet industry (server-side development work).

**Actually my career changing reason is lots of challenges , chances and good career development in internet industry.I have 
learned a lot technical knowledge related to server-side development work in my spare time, I found I also have great interest in it.**

background: I have done 2 jobs now,1st job is about HW related software development work.(windows platform)  (for one year and a half)

current job is some application development work(which requires a little HW knowledge )  under linux.(I have worked in this position one more year now )

actually the situation is the job I have done in the past to specifically prepare for the job I  am being interviewed for.

So if I say the leaving reason for current job honestly when I am in a interview held by a internet company, is there anything not well-considered?

1. Will the interviewer think my loyalty is bad for current company?

Because I work for current job just for my career change to internet industry, this maybe leave the interviewer a bad impression.

2. So obviously I didn't tell the real thought for leaving my 1st job to my current company, the interviewer can infer that I have lied to my current company for the reason leaving my 1st job .

I am concerned about the 2 issues I list above.

**Is there any better way to explain the reason I leave my current job?**
  (I really want to join in the internet industry.)

I am a foreigner, I plan to apply job in US. I know little about how Americans deal with this.

Comment: Welcome to the site lala. I'm afraid I'm having trouble identifying your core question. If you're asking if a specific reason is a bad one to give for leaving, emphasize that in your post and word it just as you'd explain it during an interview (short and to-the-point). If you're asking if you should be honest about reasons for leaving, have a look at these related questions: [1](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/9312), [2](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/30768), [3](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/42121)

Comment: thanks for you nice guys helpful advices. my English express ability maybe not well, I have thought twice for my long-term career plan, I think I am much clearer what I need in the future.(**interest, achievement,self-accomplishment**). many thanks

Comment: What was your previous field? There could be something to be said for how big of a shift is this that without knowing your previous field would be hard to answer.

Comment: thanks JB king's commence, I have added some background for this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While companies want loyal employees, they also want employees that are smart enough to make long-term plans to develop themselves so that they can create value for the firm.

Try to be honest about your career choices. If you tell the interviewer that you have taken the jobs you have done in the past to specifically prepare for the job you are being interviewed for, the interviewer should see this in a very positive light.

That said, your length of service with the current company is not very long, and they may infer that your willingness to stay with them is questionable. But you can't change your start and end dates, except by continuing with your current firm. So continue to do so until you have a strong offer in hand.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Companies are concerned about this for many reasons, as they should be. 
Don't forget you are interviewing them as well.
 I have always answered those types of inquiries with the following:

"I am looking to change companies/industries because I feel my current position doesn't allow me 
to utilize my skills effectively, and to allow myself and the organization to grow. 
While compensation is certainly important, what keeps me at a job is constant opportunities for 
growth and a forward-thinking mindset. If this company has those things and continues to have them, 
I will continue to bring my best to work every day for your company and share in its growth."

Either one of two things happen:

1. They hate this response, which says that they actually don't have these things and it's a win-win since they don't get a potential job-hopper and 
   you don't work for a crappy company.
2. They love this response, and it's a win-win because they get a great employee and you get a great employer.