# What and how to explain recruiter about quitting job due to bullying

Tags: interviewing, job-change, quitting, bullying

I have been having serious problem with my head of department.

TLDR: If I said it was day, she would argue and say it's night. She was really rude, would speak with me rudely in meetings, shout at me in meetings, always made me feel like crap - I don't even know why as my work was always excellent but she always tried to find faults but never succeed. Things started to get really bad and I started dreading going into work, my stomach would turn every morning.

I started looking for jobs and found my dream job so I applied. I got a phone interview next week but I have now quit my job as I could not take it no more.

Should I tell my recruiter or should I keep quiet?

Comment: Related: [Why is it not a good idea to "badmouth" a previous employer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/42121)

Comment: No reason to tell them you left because of bullying

Answer (score 5):

It is generally a bad idea to tell a hiring recruiter that you were bullied at your previous job.

He has no way of knowing if you were actually bullied, or are overly fragile and thus misinterpreted normal workplace interactions as personally hostile. He may not want to take the chance that you might be a troublemaking whiner.

If you display bitterness or anger toward your previous employers, a prospective future employer will classify you as "a person who displays bitterness and anger toward employers", and will expect you to eventually display bitterness or anger toward him.

Better to err on the tactful side of diplomacy and pretend that you get along with everybody.