# What is the best way to explain why I left a job after 4 months?

Tags: resume, new-job, job-change

After a little over 3 months (looks like 4 since I started in June and will be leaving in October) I decided to leave a new job.  There are many reasons: lack of support and training, isolation from colleagues, changing my supervisor 3 times, not having work from home option just for my specific position even though the website boasts of allowing their employees to work from home and all my other colleagues do.  After feeling for weeks that I didn't feel I would last long, but trying to stick it out for at least a year, I finally called it quits after my son came down with pneumonia and they weren't very understanding on why I had to take time off.  In order to avoid any drama with them, I gave my reason as wanting to spend more time with my children, especially as my son has been sick and I felt I needed to be with him.  I'm giving them a 2 weeks notice since I don't want them to think entirely negatively of me, but I'm really dreading coming in these next 2 weeks.

Now as I start to look for other jobs, I'm not sure whether to leave the job on my resume and try to find a good way to say all this without looking like I'm bashing my employer, or to just leave it off but have a 4 month+ gap on my resume depending how long it takes me to find the next job.  I had also already put it on LinkedIn, and though I suppose I could remove it, many of my former colleagues and references already know I had started there.  I suppose I could avoid saying anything negative by using the same reason I gave them, which was my son was sick and I wanted to be with him, but then I'm afraid a potential employer will also be wary to hire me knowing that I have small children who get sick frequently.  So basically I see my options as one of the ones below.

- remove the job which will show a 4 month+ gap and risk having a potential employer find out somehow
- keep the job but say that the reason I left was because my son was sick and they weren't understanding about taking the time
- keep the job and briefly explain that the position wasn't as advertised and my supervisor changed three times, and that not being understanding about taking time for my son was just the final straw

Which is the best option?

Comment: We can't answer the question at the end of your text. The one in the headline is a duplicate. Voting to close.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do I say about my previous job, which was horrible, in a new job interview?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/32590/what-do-i-say-about-my-previous-job-which-was-horrible-in-a-new-job-interview)

Answer (score 3):

**The best option is:  Be honest.**

Explaining that you had a negative working experience with the employer, there was a lack of stability (changing your manager multiple times), The job not being as advertised etc.  These are all perfectly normal, and valid reasons for leaving a job within the first few months.

The other options all lead to a negative view on you, but being honest will be more neutral.