# Is it OK to tell reason for switch is bad management?

Tags: interviewing

I am planning to switch my current company due to bad management policies like

- Micromanage employees
- Make smart people leave the company by making unnecessary strict rules
- Ignore good practice such as code review
- Hire an unfit employee and expect me to train them

There are also other points.

If I get interviewed by companies how should I tell these reason without sounding like a negative person, they might see me as complaining about everything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it not a good idea to "badmouth" a previous employer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/42121/why-is-it-not-a-good-idea-to-badmouth-a-previous-employer) or [What do I say about my previous job, which was horrible, in a new job interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/32590/what-do-i-say-about-my-previous-job-which-was-horrible-in-a-new-job-interview)

Comment: There are already the answer to your question in the question lniked by Draken, don't tell anything to your current employer and to the next. By the way, what you're describing is not so uncommon. However you can now prepare some questions for interviews that for what you will search in your job from what you didn't like here

Comment: @Draken  thanks, i didn't know that and i have marked it as duplicate