# How to prevent a brief job from hurting my job prospects

Tags: job-search, resume, united-states

I just left a company that I was at for almost 5 years for a much better job (double the pay, responsibilities that are more closely aligned with my skillset, etc.). I had a couple reservations about it (required 10-20% travel every month and one of the two managers that interviewed me was aggressive and somewhat rude). However, the other (much higher up) manager was extremely nice and seemed like he really wanted me to work for them, so I went for it.

Now, barely more than a few days after starting, I am under constant pressure. Prior to being hired they promised to work with me to minimize the travel requirement, but now they are saying it's needed. I also found out that the health insurance doesn't cover most common doctors or walk-in care centers in my area since the company is out-of-state.

I'd like to start applying for new jobs again, but I'm afraid that quitting after a few weeks will look bad to any prospective employers. Is it likely that my 4-5 year job will help balance that out or is there anything I can do (add something to my resume?) to make myself look better?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My new job is a bad fit. I want to leave after 4 months](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/138926/my-new-job-is-a-bad-fit-i-want-to-leave-after-4-months)

Answer (score 8):

> Is it likely that my 4-5 year job will help balance that out

Certainly.

Just be prepared with good answers when asked why you are leaving your new job so soon.

And, dig in deeply on prospective jobs as you search. Talk with your prospective boss and peers to understand the kind of pressure you can expect. Make sure you understand and are willing to comply with travel requirements. And ask about the insurance before accepting an offer.

Mistakes happen. What seems appealing ("double the pay") can sometimes turn out to be an intolerable situation. Most hiring managers will understand a one-time issue like this. But you don't want it to happen again.

Answer (score 4):

You're completely overthinking this.  Get a new job that suits your needs.  Leave this little "mistake" off your resume.  If anyone presses you over the short gap, tell them that you had an opportunity that simply wasn't a good fit.  Generally, no one will care about such a short gap.

Comment: In fact if you get a new job within 50 days the gap will magically disappear:  'Old Job' ... to Feb 2022, new job, March 2022 to ... ;  it's only really if you have a pattern of doing it repeatedly you need to start proactively explaining things.

Answer (score 3):

Bottom line:  It won't matter after your next job.

Provided you stay at your next job a bit, this job will not matter.  If you are asked why you left a job so soon, tell the truth:  "the travel requirements were surprising and overwhelming".

It was stupid that this employer misrepresented the travel requirements as this will result in your leaving and thus a lot of wasted time and costs.  More so for them then you.

You may want to, in the future, omit this position from your resume.  It is unlikely that you gained any valuable skills or did anything worth mentioning in your short tenure.

Don't worry about it, the bottom line is that companies are looking to fill needs and provided you meet the qualifications this will mean nothing.  Many have "been there, got treated that way, and left soon after".

Answer (score 0):

A resume does not need to be comprehensive, it's meant to summarize relevant work experience and demonstrate to employers what you have to offer. You certainly aren't required to include negligible or irrelevant work experience - quite the opposite, you are expected to skip them and get to the point!

It's not uncommon for people to leave out old jobs (e.g. 15+ years), irrelevant experience (e.g. entry-level service jobs in unrelated industries) or extremely short term positions. A resume isn't a permanent record, it's supposed to be a relatively concise summary of your (relevant!) work experience.

That leaves a gap in your resume, true, but a few weeks is hardly going to raise any eyebrows. It's not uncommon to have short gaps between jobs, just be prepared to explain it in case anyone asks. Give an honest explanation, but there is no need to actively bring up a negligible employment period unless asked. Badmouthing a former employer (however brief) is never good, and most of that gap will be spent on the job hunt anyway.

In short, you don't really have anything to worry about. Don't include it in the resume, and be prepared to explain the gap (though I doubt anyone will care very much about it).

Comment: Sure, but why would that be a problem? Leaving a job after a few days/weeks is completely negligible work experience. It doesn't belong on a resume to begin with, and there no reason to bring it up unprompted.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you should not mention this one under employment

put it in the projects section, if you want to keep it on your resume