# How to explain a 2 month job

Tags: interviewing, resume

I left a job after 2 month and i have it in my resume.

my reason was because some teammates did not seem to want to work. i had some litirally apply makeup while on duty. Its a front desk job at a busy restaurant. some team memebers just dissappear on peak hours.
I explained to management in first month but nothing was done.
These are collegues who are on this job for more than a year
I just forcasted that this will be my work enviroment for the next year or years so i quit.

I am concerned that this will not go well with employers and might seem like i do not get a long with my coworkers.

how to explain the short job in a professional way.

thanks

Comment: @Joe my thinking is that by the time i find the next job i would have picked up bad work ethics from my current job. basically wasting time. I probably need to improve on my job retention under any circumstances for a year as a rule.

Comment: *Be ready to talk about it* LOL, they are literally asking right now. Explaining that work ethics is an issue shows willingness to work. However, don't badmouth former employers.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler: To some it may show a willingness to work, to others it may look like an excuse to quit a perfectly good job. Bottom line is, regardless of their ethics, those employees are working harder than the OP who isn't even working at all right now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent a brief job from hurting my job prospects](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/182631/how-to-prevent-a-brief-job-from-hurting-my-job-prospects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to explain the short job in a professional way.

You'll need to explain why you left so quickly and so abruptly. Be honest.

You'll also need to explain why you won't leave your new job so quickly.

Comment: No tangble actions from management. The other part that lead me to quit is my consern that under these curcmestances my evaluation will not go well.

Comment: I am all for honesty, but on this occasion I would avoid being too honest. Nobody want's to hire a snitch.

Answer (score 2):

> The team didn't live up to what I think of as appropriate professional standards.

This is obviously a lot easier to handle if:

- You've had long term jobs in the past
- You don't have any other short term jobs in the past
- This isn't your most recent role
- You can provide examples of how you *have* got along with teammates in the past.