# applying to same position but in a different department

Tags: interviewing

I am applying to a same position that I currently hold in my company but in a different department.  I'm burned out, doing overtime 4 out of 5 days with no end in sight, but I certainly don't want to give those reasons for the change during my interview. What diplomatic reasons can I give for the change ? I have been in the current position for 2yrs and 7months. Tks.

Comment: Say true things or make things up, your only two choices really.

Comment: What is your job? Makes a big difference to the answer.

Comment: So you're working on a project that requires overtime and burns you out, and you don't wish to partake anymore? Hopefully you've brought this up beforehand, because it's likely the company will want a pretty good reason for the move

Comment: Check out this answer: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/9314/62982. The philosophy of how to answer applies almost across the board, whether it's only internally or externally.

Answer (score 1):

Stress the positive things about the department you would be going to, rather than negative things about where you are now.  Something like "I've always been interested in..." or "I think it's time to broaden my skill set".